# Filter using date range in separate data frame - R

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a unique list of investors that have held target stock within the past 6 months of a merger taking place.

I have two separate data frames that I'm using for this purpose:
- df1 contains investor ID, stock ID, date, and portfolio holdings of stock.
- df2 contains acquirer stock ID, target stock ID, and date of merger.

```
investor stock  date            portfolio holdings
629      10     01/01/1990      100
629      10     02/01/1990      100
629      10     03/01/1990      70
629      10     04/01/1990      50
629      10     05/01/1990      0
629      10     06/01/1990      0
664      10     04/01/1990      100
664      10     05/01/1990      100
664      10     06/01/1992      100
664      12     10/10/1992      100
664      12     11/10/1992      100
1020     10     12/12/1995      50
1020     10     13/12/1995      25
1020     10     14/12/1995      25
1020     10     15/12/1995      0
...      ...    ...             ...
```

```
acquirer stock  target stock    date of merger
100             10              06/01/1990
101             12              10/10/1992
102             14              15/12/1995
...             ...             ...
```

For each merger, I want to filter out those investors that have held any volume of target stock above 0 within the 6 months prior to the merger taking place. It doesn't matter that the investor's portfolio holdings on the date of merger is 0, if they've held a positive volume within 6 months prior to it.

All I need is a list of those investors that have held target stock as seen below. I will use this list as a filter for a larger data set later on.

```
investor
629
664
…
```

Investor 629 is chosen because she had a positive holding of stock 10 within 6 months prior to the merger date. Investor 664 is chosen based on her holdings of both stock 10 and 12. Investor 1020 is not chosen because although she holds stock 10, it's not within 6 months of the merger date.

Comment: Sharing data with `dput` will help us replicate the issue.

Comment: Hi iaa123. Can you please give us some more details? For instance I'm not sure I got how you selected `629`. You kept it because on the `06/01/1990` you have some information about his/her stock `10` (even if his/her holding is 0). Is it so? If so, I would point you the `merge` function (https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/merge) combined with `unique` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/unique)

Comment: Tried to make the selection process more clear now. The investors are selected if they hold a stock at or 6 months prior to merger date. I don't have any further information about the stock/investor other than the portfolio holdings @BrunoZamengo

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I `merge` the two datasets. Merging them means carrying out a join-like operation.

```
df3 = merge (
    df1, df2,
    by.x = "stock", by.y = "target stock"
)
```

`df3` is the merged dataset.
It contains all `df1` and all `df2` columns and rows. I matched the two dataset where the condition `stock = target stock` is satisfied.
Please, have a look at the `merge` function for further details (just type `?merge` in the R console).

```
df4 = df3

tmp = sapply(
    df4[, "date of merger"], 
    function(d) as.Date(seq(d, length = 2, by = "-6 months")[2])
)

df4[, "date of merger start"] = as.Date(tmp, origin = "1970-01-01")

df4
```

I then add a new column. This new column subtracts 6 months from `date of merger`: I will use it to check which rows respect the condition

```
"date of merger -6 months" <= "date" <= "date of merger"
```

I keep only rows where the condition is met:

```
df5 = subset(
    df4, "portfolio holdings" > 0 & "date" <= "date of merger" & "date of merger start" <= "date"
)

df5
```

Look at `subset` help (`?subset`) for further details.

You state you are interested in `investor` distinct values only:

```
unique(df5[, "investor"])
```

---

**NOTES**

- I have had some issues testing the code so it may need some fixes, but this is how I would personally solve the problem
- There are many different solutions which you may find, I cannot warantee you this is the best one
- The code should be optimized (avoid creating useless objects like `tmp`, `df3` and `df4`: I added them as intermediate steps to make it easier to debug/understand :)
- I would suggest to carry out these kind of operations (basically, data filtering) from a DB using SQL